# How do I remove a broken apt repo?

Tags: updates, sudo

The system update stopped working, and now i can't update it nor from terminal nor from the via app store.

This what happens when i update from the [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter):

[image: This what happens when i update from the app store:]

This what happens when i update from the [terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal):
[image]

Comment: This isn't a question about Elementary. You installed a repository for elementary tweaks (not part of the OS) which seems broken.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily && sudo apt update
```

And if you want to use elementary-tweaks use [this one](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks). It's a fork of the one you've been trying to add but with more settings.

By the way, you seem to be using Juno beta. You might want to update to the stable version since it's already out!